# Java Regular Expression - how to use backslash

Tags: java, regex

I am really confused with how to escape. Sometimes I just need to prepend a backslash but sometimes I need to prepend double backslash like `"\\."`.
Could any one tell me why?

Also, could anyone give me an explanation of difference in

- `String.split("\t")`,
- `String.split("\\t")`,
- `String.split("\\\t")`,
- `String.split("\\\\t")`?

Comment: You could just edit your question instead of adding a comment and leaving the incorrect text.

Comment: Add as many backslash you can until it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backslash is special character in string literals - we can use it to create `\n` or escape `"` like `\"`.

But backslash is also special in regular expression engine - for instance we can use it to use default character classes like `\w` `\d` `\s`.

So if you want to create string which will *represent* regex/text like `\w` you need to write it as `"\\w"`.

If you want to write regex which will represent `\` literal then text representing such regex needs to look like `\\` which means String representing such text needs to be written as `"\\\\"`.
In other words we need to escape backslash twice:

- once in regex `\\`
- and once in string `"\\\\"`.

If you want to pass to regex engine literal which will represent tab then you don't need to escape backslash at all. Java will understand `"\t"` string as string representing tab character and you can pass such string to your regex engine without problems.

For our comfort regex engine in Java interprets text representing `\t` (also `\r` and `\n`) same way as string literals interpret `"\t"`. In other words we can pass to regex engine text which will represent `\` character and `t` character and be sure that it will be interpreted as representation of tab character.

So code like `split("\t")` or `split("\\t")` will try to split on tab.

Code like `split("\\\\t")` will try to split text not on tab character, but on `\` character followed by `t`. It happens because `"\\\\"` as explained represents text `\\` which regex engine sees as escaped `\` (so it is treated as literal).

Comment: I am working on explanation of `String.split("\\\t")`. It looks like regex engine allows text `\[tab]` represent `[tab]`. I don't know why it is. I would expect exception here since such expression is most probably result of mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer solved my confusion. But I still have a question, what is the result of String.split("\\a")? "\\a" will means "\a" in regex, but what does this regex represent?

Comment: Yes `"\\a"` stands for `\a` regex (text which is passed to regex engine) and according to Pattern class documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\a` represents "The alert (bell) character ('\u0007')".

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! Your answer is very comprehensive and really helpful.